# Error dependency is not satisfiable yad(>=0.24.1)

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am trying to install newsup (http://newsupapp.weebly.com) but I get this error.

> error dependency is not satisfiable yad(>=0.24.1)

I get this error in gdebi and the software center.

I have tried

> sudo apt-get install -f

I am guessing I need a package called yad how would I go about finding it?

I am running Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `yad` isn't available for 15.04 using the officially Ubuntu repositories. Wily (15.10) has the package.

To use the package with Vivid, you need an PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yad
```